# Eclipse Plugin Not "Resolved" after installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am installing some few plugins created by us in Eclipse. But a few of the plugins(let's say plugin A) after installation shows only "Installed" and not `Resolved` or `Starting`. For that to be `Resolved`, I need to restart with `-clean` option.  This doesn't happen with plugin B(let's say), it gets `Resolved` or `Starting`.

I have also tried installing from cmd-

```
 eclipsec -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://path/to/plugin -installIU com.abc.feature.feature.group  -destination //path/to/home -consoleLog  -clean
```

Again, this works for plugin B, not Plugin A. But if I first install A and then install B, then A shows `Resolved`. Is this some property of A? If so, can we change the default state of a plugin after install? And, can I trigger A via some way, without starting eclipse with a `-clean`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To find out why plug-in/bundle A is not resolved, you can do the following:

1. Add `org.eclipse.equinox.console` to your Eclipse installation (if it's not there yet)
2. **Start Eclipse** from the command line with the arguments **`-console -noexit -consoleLog`**
3. In the Eclipse **OSGi console** type **`diag <bundle ID of plug-in A>`** to find out what prevents resolving bundle A.

See also: [Eclipse Wiki - Where Is My Bundle](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle)